# Xamarin app can't run in release mode on iPhone (This app cannot be installed becaue its integrity could not be verified)

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios-provisioning

This is a question that has been asked several times, but no solution has worked for me.
I finished coding a Xamarin Forms app and now, I want to release it. I signed the app with a new certificate and an Adhoc provisioning profile. Everything signs well.
But when I distribute the IPA, after installing the app, iOS shows this message:

> "This app cannot be installed becaue its integrity could not be
> verified"

I chosed Ad-hoc as provisioning profile config.

This app has the same namespace and bundle id as its preceding app found in the app store already. I built a new version, within a new solution and created certificates with the same bundle id.

The device on which I am trying to install it is an iPhone XR, that I use to test the live version of the app and the one in development. When I run the app in debug on the phone, nothing wrong happens. But signing and distributing causes the app to not run.

Comment: There must be an app with the same namespace and bundle id on the  phone that is why the issue. Can you confirm that you have deleted the already existent app from iphone XR. Try this.

Comment: So the thing is 
 Remove the already existing app that is probably from the app store from the device and then install the app you created through ADHOC profile

Comment: I deleted the existing app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of debugging, I found out that my bundle display name for the new version of the app was written in lower case, whereas the bundle display name of the former app was camel case. When I changed the new app's bundle display name to camel case too, everything went smoothly.
This is so weird.